# Cannot enable org-roam mode - No EmacSQL SQLite binary available (windows 10)

Tags: org-mode, init-file, terminal-emacs, error-handling

Cannot make `org-roam` work under windows 10 because I get "No EmacSQL SQLite binary available".

### What I've done:

- Installed `org-roam` using `M-x install-package`.
- Installed `emacsql-sqlite3` using `M-x install-package`.
- I have compiled the makefile in emacsql-sqlite folder via ubuntu's bash on windows 10.

P.S. I have tried following instructions on org-roam website. It's still not working.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Install sqlite3?

Comment: Or to put it another way, can you invoke sqlite3 from the command line? outside of emacs? If not, then you probably need to install it - see e.g. [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm).